# Strange behavior with Push notification ios in app in Background

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am sending a push notification with the following payload:

```
{"aps":{"alert":{"loc-key":"general","loc-args":["Test DEFAULT."]},"badge":1,"sound":"default"}}
```

in the the localization string, i have it defined as such:

```
"general"="%@";
```

While the app is open, the notification is fine since I handle it when I get the response from apple. But when the app is in the background or terminated, I would get "general" as the title and "general" in the body in the notification.

Not to sure what is going on, since the structure I have seems to match what apple has documented.

Comment: When your app is backgrounded, the OS does the local notification for you, I'm not sure about localisation though, are you expecting it to get applied?

Comment: well I was expecting to have loc-args filled in the localized string in the placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the app can't find your localization string. Make sure there isn't any problem with your Localizable.strings file for the current language selected by the user.

Comment: don't think there is a problem, I am able to loaded the localized strings pretty well